# If $a,b,x,y$ are real and $a^2 + b^2 = 81, x^2 + y^2 = 121$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $a, b, x, y$ be real numbers such $a^2+b^2=81$, $x^2+y^2=121$ and $ax + by = 99$. The set of
> all possible values of $ay - bx$ is:
>
> A. $(0,9/11]$
>
> B. $(0,9/11)$
>
> C. ${0}$
>
> D. $[9/11, \infty)$

I have already solved the problem and obtained $0$ as the correct answer. I did it by first multiplying the first two equations and then subtracting the square of the third from it. This gave me $(ay-bx)^2=0$.

However, when I try to substitute in values such as $a=±9,b=0,x=±11,y=0$ I found the given expression to be $=±99$, and more generally values other than $0$. Although it's almost definitely something trivial, I just don't understand what am I missing here. Can someone please help me out? Thanks

Comment: You forgot the condition $ax+by = 99$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a = \pm 9 , b = x = 0 , y = \pm 11$, the condition $ax+by = 99$ is *not satisfied*, so this does not count. Note that all of $a^2+b^2 = 81, x^2+y^2 = 121$ *and* $ax+by = 99$ need to hold for $ay -bx = 0$ to hold, else it will vary. Note that
$$
(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2) = (ax+by)^2 + (ay-bx)^2
$$

so if you don't fix any of those three values, the others will definitely vary.

---

EDIT : In comments below, $a=\pm 9, b = y = 0, x = 11$ was suggested : this fits the framework, but $ay-bx = 0$, which is not different from the expected result. Furthermore, the identity used here is called Brahmagupta identity, and also shows that if we take the product of two numbers which can be written as the sum of two squares, that product can also be written in such a form.

Comment: I made a typo, if we have $x=11$ and $y=0$ then what is the problem?

Comment: @l1mbo Then in fact $ay-bx = 0$, because $b=y=0$, so you just get back what you had. If the identity is correct, then your only errors can be calculation errors.

Comment: ah shoot, so I made a stupid mistake while substituting the value in the final equation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. In the event the answer was helpful, kindly upvote and accept (when possible) one of the available answers so we can close the question.

Comment: I tried to but there seems to be a rule that we need to wait at least 6 minutes before we can close the answer

Comment: Yes, you need to wait 15 minutes starting from when you have asked to accept an answer. This is so that there is time for new answers to come in.

Comment: "Cultural" remark : You have used the so-called Brahmagupta's identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity in its version $n=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution:

Let $a = 9 \cos p, b = 9 \sin p$, $x = 11 \cos q, y = 11 \sin q$, where $p, q \in \mathbb R$ and are in $[0, 2\pi)$.

Then conditions $1$ and $2$ are satisfied by the Pythagorean identity, and all that is left is the third condition $ax + by = 99$. This gives $99 \cos p \cos q + 99 \sin p \sin q = 99$, or that $\cos(p-q) = 1 \Rightarrow p - q = 0$. Thus $p = q$.

Then $ay - bx = 99 \cos p \sin q - 99 \sin p \cos q = -99\sin(p-q)$. However, since $p = q$, the value of $ay - bx$ is just $-99 \sin 0 = \boxed{0}$.

Comment: Always cool to see alternative solutions, thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

We have: $$(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2) - (ax+by)^2 = 81*121 - 99^2 = 0$$
After simplification we get:
$$(ay)^2 + (bx)^2 - 2aybx = 0$$
Which give us: $$(ay - bx)^2 = 0$$ Hence: $$ay - bx = 0$$
So the answer is C.